# Density of $W=\frac{X+Y}{2}$

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, random-variables, exponential-function

Let $X$ a random variable with uniform distribution in $(1,a)$. Knowing that $\mathbb{E}(X)=6Var(X)$,

1) find the value of $a$.

2) find the distribution of $Y=-log(\frac{X-1}{a-1})$.

3) if $Z$ is another variable with the same distribution of $X$ and indipendent of $X$, find the law of $W=\frac{X+Y}{2}$.

---

1) $a=3$ because the second solution ($a=0$) is not acceptable for the positivity of density.

2) $f_Y(y)=\mathbb{P}(X\geq 1+(a-1)e^{-y})=\int_{1+(a-1)e^{-y}}^{a}\frac{1}{a-1}dx=1-e^{-y}\Rightarrow Y\sim Exp(1)$.

3) The problem is here. I did $F_W(w)=\mathbb{P}(W\leq w)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq 2w-Z)=\int_{1}^{a}[\int_{1}^{2w-z}\frac{1}{(a-1)^2}dx]dz$ but the result is not correct. I don't understand where I wrong. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your $f_Y(y)$ should be $P(Y\le y)$. And it probably should be $W=(X+Z)/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of integration is not correct.

$z$ doesn't always run from $1$ to $a$. It runs from $1$ to $\min(a,  2w-1)$.

Also, we only integrate $x$ from $1$ to $\min(a, 2w-z)$.

The pictures illustrate the cases to consider:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Observing the domain you've drawn, I'm arrived to say that $F_W(w)={{0, w<1; \frac{2(w-1)^2}{(a-1)^2}, 1\leq w< \frac{(a+1)}{2}; 1-\frac{2(w-1)^2}{(a-1)^2}, \frac{(a+1)}{2}\leq w< 1; 1, w \geq 1}}$. The only thing I don't understand is why calculating $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}(\frac{2(w-1)^2}{(a-1)^2})$ i obtain $\frac{4(w-1)}{(a-1)^2}$ (correctly) while calculating $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}(1- \frac{2(w-1)^2}{(a-1)^2})$ i obtain a negative density. Could you please explain me this fact? Thanks again in advance!

Comment: If your part $a$ is correct, then we have $a=3$, and $\frac{a+1}2=2$ which is less than $1$. that is $\frac{a+1}{2} \le w \le 1$ is reduced to $2 \le w \le 1$ which doesn't make sense isn't it?